# How to get styling to refresh with new variable in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Using a global variable to store dark and light mode variable. In app I have place where variable is changed as user toggles if they want dark or light theme, but I cannot figure out how to get styling to refresh with this new variable once I have changed it. I know this is probably not the best way to go about it but can anyone help me out here?

```
/*  Universal styling page, all styling on pages is located here
    Styling is adjusted by window and screen dimensions so that
    styling will look nice on multiple devices of varying sizes
*/
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, Appearance} from 'react-native';;

const window = Dimensions.get("window");
const screen = Dimensions.get("screen");
//const colorScheme = 'dark'
let pref = Appearance.getColorScheme();
global.COLORSCHEME = [pref];
const darkTheme = "#1A1A1A"
const lightTheme = "#FAFAFA"

export default StyleSheet.create({
    noPadContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: COLORSCHEME[0]==="dark" ? darkTheme : lightTheme,

    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 24,
        backgroundColor: COLORSCHEME[0]==="dark" ? darkTheme : lightTheme
    },
    TextInput: {
        backgroundColor: COLORSCHEME[0]==="dark" ? "grey" : "#FAFAFA",
    },
    overlay: {
        flex: 2,
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        opacity: COLORSCHEME[0]==="dark" ? 0.7 : 1.0,
        backgroundColor: COLORSCHEME[0]==="dark" ? 'black' : 'transparent',
        width: window.width,
        height: window.height,
        alignItems:"center",
        marginHorizontal: 0,
    },
    generalOverlay: {
        flex: 1,
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        opacity: COLORSCHEME[0]==="dark" ? 0.7 : 1.0,
        backgroundColor: COLORSCHEME[0]==="dark" ? 'black' : 'transparent',
        width: window.width,
        height: window.height,
        marginHorizontal: 0,
    },
    generalButtonContained: {
        //backgroundColor: "#6200ed"
        backgroundColor: COLORSCHEME[0]==="dark" ? '#332940' : '#6200ed',
        color: COLORSCHEME[0]==="dark" ? '#696969' : '#FAFAFA',
    },
    generalButton: {
        color: COLORSCHEME[0]==="dark" ? '#696969' : '#FAFAFA',
    },
    generalText: {
        color: COLORSCHEME[0]==="dark" ? '#696969' : 'black',
    },
    scrollview: {
        flex: 2,
        alignItems:"center",
        marginHorizontal: 0,
        //paddingBottom: bottomNavigatorBarHeight
    },
    centerPage: {
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems:"center"
    },
    centerPageMargin: {
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems:"center",
        marginTop: 40,
        
    },
    tinyLogo:{
        width: screen.width*.6,
        height: screen.height*.25,
        marginTop: 10,
        alignItems: "center",
        marginTop: "25%",
    },
    cardStyleWelcome: {
        backgroundColor: "grey",
    },
    buttonStyle: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        minWidth: screen.width*.4,
        minHeight: screen.height*.18,
        maxWidth: screen.width*.45,
        maxHeight: screen.height*.25,
        textAlign: "center",
        backgroundColor: COLORSCHEME[0]==="dark" ? '#332940' : '#6200ed',
        //backgroundColor: "#7F46C7",
        borderRadius: 20,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: COLORSCHEME[0]==="dark" ? '#696969' : 'white',
        elevation: 10,
        justifyContent: "center",
        
    },
    textStyle: {
        
        //color: "#6200ed",
        color: COLORSCHEME[0]==="dark" ? '#a1a1a1' : 'white',
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems:"center",
        textAlign: "center",
        fontWeight: '500',
        fontSize: 14,
        fontFamily: "System",
        textTransform: "uppercase",
        letterSpacing: 1,
        marginVertical: 9,
        marginHorizontal: 16,
    },
    modalText: {
        color: "white",
        justifyContent: "flex-start",
        alignItems:"flex-start",
        textAlign: "center",
        fontWeight: '500',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontFamily: "System",
        textTransform: "uppercase",
        marginHorizontal: 10,
    },
    modalStyle: {
        
        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
        shadowRadius: 4,
        elevation: 5,
        margin: 0,
        
        alignItems:"center",
        textAlign: "center",
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.25)',
    
    },
    
    viewStyle: {
        flex:-1,
        flexDirection:"row",
        marginTop: 10,
    },
    cardStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "powderblue",
    margin: 10,
    },
    label: {
    color: "black",
    },
    title: {
    margin: 8,
    color: "#20232a",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "600",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    },
    buttonStyleT:{
        backgroundColor :"silver"
    },
    scheduleHeight: {
        height: screen.height * .82
    }
});;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can use a react context for this purpose and build a fully responsive user first solution something like this:

```js
import React, {FC} from 'react';
import {Appearance, Button, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

// dark theme
const darkStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  noPadContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
});

// light theme
const lightStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  noPadContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});

// styles context
export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  theme: lightStyles,
  toggle: () => {},
});

export const useTheme = () => React.useContext(ThemeContext);

export const ThemeProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [userTheme, setUserTheme] = React.useState();
  const [theme, setTheme] = React.useState(
    Appearance.getColorScheme() || 'light',
  );

  const contextValue = React.useMemo(
    () => ((userTheme || theme) === 'dark' ? darkStyles : lightStyles),
    [userTheme, theme],
  );

  const toggleTheme = React.useCallback(async () => {
    const newTheme = (userTheme || theme) === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light';
    setUserTheme(newTheme);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('theme', newTheme);
  }, [theme, userTheme]);

  const restoreTheme = React.useCallback(async () => {
    const _userTheme = await AsyncStorage.getItem('theme');
    if (_userTheme) {
      setUserTheme(_userTheme);
    }
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    restoreTheme();
  }, [restoreTheme]);

  // listen for changes in user preference
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!userTheme) {
      const subscription = Appearance.addChangeListener(({colorScheme}) => {
        if (colorScheme) {
          setTheme(colorScheme);
        }
      });

      return () => {
        subscription.remove();
      };
    }
  }, [userTheme]);

  // render the theme
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{theme: contextValue, toggle: toggleTheme}}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

// use it in a component
const MyComponent: FC = () => {
  const {theme, toggle} = useTheme();

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={theme.noPadContainer} />
      <Button title="Toggle Theme" onPress={toggle} />
    </View>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <MyComponent />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I think this is for typescript, I am doing this in javascript so some of these declarations do not work- I get the concept of what you are trying to do, but this syntax is slightly complicated, as I am new to this.

Comment: I updated it to js version

Comment: How do I toggle my theme in another file- I have a switch where I want to toggle between dark and light mode in my settings. How would I go about this?

Comment: You can access it through useTheme hook will return current theme value and a toggle function

Comment: @Nilsen I updated the code for toggle usage